# How can I localize my UITabBarItems?

Tags: ios, localization, uitabbar

I'm beginning to learn how to localize iOS applications and hit a wall while trying to localize my UITabBarItems.

Note that these were created in interface builder (using XCode 4).

Is there a way to do this or would I need to create the UITabBarController using just code and manually inserting a localized string for each UITabBarItem?

Cheers

PS:

I do know that I can set the tile of a UITabBarItem by setting the view controller's title like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Test", @"");
}
```

... but this only woks once you hit the tab bar item. Before that it just shows what you put in interface builder...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It seems to work if you set `title` in `awakeFromNib` instead:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Test", @"");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

On Swift 3 and 4:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.title = NSLocalizedString("Test", comment: "")
}
```